# Proving that if n is uneven, then n+5 is even

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I would think that of the five answers on the multiple choice the following one marked in bold is the correct one:

Answer 5.1: ∃k ∈ Z: n = 2(k + 1) ⇒
∃k ∈ Z: n + 5 = 2(k + 1) + 5 = 2(k + 3) + 1

Answer 5.2: ∃k ∈ Z: n + 5 = 2k ⇒
∃k ∈ Z: n = 2k − 5 = 2(k − 3) + 1

Answer 5.3: ∃k ∈ Z: n = 2k + 1 ⇒
∃k ∈ Z: n + 5 = 2k + 6 = 2(k + 3)

**Answer 5.4: ∃k ∈ Z: n = 2k ⇒
∃k ∈ Z: n + 5 = 2k + 5 = 2(k + 2) + 1**

Answer 5.5: ∃k ∈ Z: n + 5 = 2k + 1 ⇒
∃k ∈ Z: n = 2k − 4 = 2(k − 2)

Comment: The third selection is correct.  We are given that is $n$ *uneven*, meaning, *n is odd*.

Comment: If there is a $k$ such that $n = 2k$, then is $n$ even or "uneven"? (Odd is the usual terminology for "uneven") 5.4 is assuming that $n$ is an even integer, not odd, so it is incorrect.

Comment: Of course yes. I get it now. :)

It's a conditional (or implication) stating that given p is n = 2k + 1 (the usual math definition of odd) then n + 5 = 2k + 5 = 2(k + 2) + 1

Comment: I would of course rep. you if I could, still thanks a lot. :) I'm prepping for an exam.

Answer (score 1):

Translate them into plain language. $\exists k \in \mathbb Z : n = 2k$ means n is even and $\exists k \in \mathbb Z : n = 2k + 1$ means n is odd. The five choices are then

1. If n is even, then n+5 is odd
2. If n+5 is even, then n is odd
3. If n is odd, then n+5 is even
4. If n is even, then n+5 is odd
5. If n+5 is odd, then n is even

From this, it is clear that the third option is correct.

Comment: Thank you. I'll add your explanation to my evernote notebook. It was very good.